# Error when upgrading from IE8 to IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a migration project from IE8 to IE11. My job is mostly to fix CSS errors, but I also encountered some issues with the JavaScript.

In my `master.jsp` page, I have this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: toFullPath('/getID.do')
        ,type: "POST"
        ,cache: false
        ,dataType: "text"
        ,success: function(data) {
            var jsonData = null;
            try {
                jsonData = jQuery.secureEvalJSON(data);
            } catch(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('Failed to start.');
                }, 10);
                return;
            }
            $.appconf.systemId = jsonData.systemId;
            setTimeout(function() {
                startSystem(document.forms['startForm'], toFullPath('/showLoginPageAction.do'));
            }, 10);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This script runs fine in IE8, IE9, IE10

When this script is run in IE11, it keeps failing. After debugging I found out that the value of the `data` variable is different in the two versions of IE.

In IE8 it is a valid JSON:

```
"
{"ID":"001","system_changes":{}}
"
```

But in IE11, it appears to be the content of the master page:

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\" />\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=shift_jis\">\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Script-Type\" content=\"text/javascript\">\
```

(Sorry I can't copy the full content because it will be too long.)

As I understand, the `data` will be generated by `getID.do`, but when I use debug mode, it seems that this page is never accessed.

Where is this `data` coming form? Why there are differences in the two browser versions?

**UPDATE :**

Using Fiddler, I Found out that both IE versions send the same request to the action :

```
POST /src/getID.do HTTP/1.1
```

In IE8, the server response with a Json content and http code as `200`

But in IE11, the http code of the response is 302, what does this mean?

Comment: What does the `toFullPath()` function return? (Is that the part that behaves differently in IE11, causing it to make a request to the wrong url?)

Comment: @nnnnnn it will return the domain, for example : current sub-domain is `src`, `toFullPath('/getID.do')` will return `src/getID.do`, I checked bold IE verions, they return the same url

Comment: Sorry it will return `/src/getID.do`

Comment: I also edited the question, the script runs fine in IE8/9/10

Comment: @nnnnnn after researching a little bit more, the `sub-domain` I mention is the `Context Root ` : return `$.appconf.contextRoot + actionpath;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT.

It was the user-agent string which causes the problem. The solution is to modify the code on the server to check for IE11's user-agent string as well.

```
public boolean isValidIE(String strAgent) {
    if (1==1){
        return true;
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\sMSIE\\s(\\d{1,}\\.\\d{1,})[^;]*;.*");

    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(strAgent);
    if(!match.matches()) {
        Pattern patternIE11 = Pattern.compile(".*Trident.*rv:.*");
        Matcher matcherIE11 = patternIE11.matcher(strAgent);
        if(matcherIE11.matches()){
            return true;
        }   
        return false;
    }
    String ver = match.group(1);
    float version = Float.parseFloat(ver);
    if(version >= 8) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "as well"?  Meaning you are doing user agent sniffing on the server, but neglected to mention anything about that?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch honestly I don't know how "they" transfer the `user-agent` string to the server (a .java file which I only found out by luck not by debugging) for processing, so I only added one more regex to determine if the `user-agent` is IE11.